# Using Iron-node on windows 10

Tags: npm, window, iron-node

I'm having an issue running iron-node on Windows 10.  I have it installed on my Mac no problem.  However, when I try to use it using gitbash (or bash inside the windows cmd) .  I'm able to launch iron-node itself from the command prompt, but not launch it with a file I'm trying to work on (aka, I type iron-node and it pops up, but not iron-node server.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cmd.exe. It is the only supported commandline.

Comment: I ended up going with Jam3's devtool.  Works almost as good. [link](https://github.com/Jam3/devtool)